# Handsontable v0.34.0 not working with requirejs

Tags: webpack, requirejs, handsontable

I am using Handsontable v0.34.0 and trying to integrate using requirejs
my require config is correct as I can see all files loading fine like moment, numbro and pikaday.
But when I run the call following code

```
require(['jquery', 'handsontable'], function ($, Handsontable) {
    let container = document.getElementById('container');
    let hot = new Handsontable(container, {
        data: dataSet,
        width: 584,
        height: 320,
        colWidths: 47,
        rowHeights: 23,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        renderAllRows: true
    });
});
```

I get error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Handsontable is not a constructor
```

I **strongly** doubt that this has something to do with `webpack` code in the `handsontable.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting **h**andsontable to **H**andsontable in code and require-config solved the problem. I didnt have to do any change to distributed file.

```
require(['jquery', 'handsontable'], function ($, Handsontable) {
```

to

```
require(['jquery', 'Handsontable'], function ($, Handsontable) {
```